# Is it possible to recreate the contract artifacts with Truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

When trying to interact with a deployed contract I'm getting uncaught errors.

For example if I try something simple as getting the name of the contract:

```
let instance = await [contract].deployed()
await instance.name()
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught:
{
  code: -32000,
  message: 'err: max fee per gas less than block base fee: address [contract address], maxFeePerGas: 29000000000 baseFee: 51252996185 (supplied gas 3800000)'
}
```

I got a feeling this has something to do with the contract artifacts. So I was wondering if its possible to recreate the contract artifacts with Truffle?

Comment: The contract is deployed on which network ? Ganache ?

Comment: @clement it's deployed on the mainnet.

Comment: The error is related to the London hard fork. Can you try update Truffle with the last release (post hard fork) (https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases) ?

Comment: I've updated to 5.4.3 and 5.4.4 but having the same problem.